# How to remove first row and first column from a matrix-like dataset

Tags: python

I have constructed eigenvector matrix using R and output it in a file that looks like this:

```
"","values","vectors.1","vectors.2","vectors.3","vectors.4","vectors.5","vectors.6"
"1",5,0.49,0.40,-0.577,0,0.28,-0.4
"2",4,0,-0.40,0.283,0.5,0.577,-0.4
"3",3,-0.5,0.4,0.28,-0.5,0.28,-0.
"4",3,0.5,-0.4,0.28,-0.5,-0.28,-0.4
"5",1,-0.5,-0.4,-0.57,0,-0.28,-0.4
"6",0,0,0.4,0.28,0.5,-0.57,-0.4
```

I want to remove the first row and first column to extract the matrix itself and store it in another file (I believe you cannot do read and write in the same file you open). Hence, I tried the following but I don't know how to proceed. Appreciate any help.

```
with open('./test.csv', 'r') as csvfile, open('./output.csv', 'w') as outputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        print line[0][3:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and write to CSV files without using the `csv` module. You can iterate through all the lines, except for the first line, then write all the rows of each line, except for the first row, to the output file, like so:

```
with open('./test.csv', 'r') as input_file, open('./output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    for index, line in enumerate(input_file):
        if index != 0:
            output_file.write(",".join(line.split(",")[1:]))
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like:

```
new_file = open("new.csv", "a") # opens/creates new.csv to append the results
with open('old.csv') as f: # opens csv file for reading
    f.next() # skips the first line
    for line in f: # loop all lines in old.csv
        new_file.write(",".join(line.split(",")[1:])) # append to new.csv

new_file.close() # closes new.csv
```